# Using non-blocking code from blocking code to reduce number of threads being used

Tags: java, spring-mvc, asynchttpclient

In case of blocking APIs the caller expects code to return some value.

e.g. `response = blockingAPI.execute()`

In case of non-blocking code, we communicate via callbacks.

The overall request (web) pipeline is blocking and sequential. Steps depend on response of previous steps. In one of the step we need to call a web service. The current setup assumes this service to be called using blocking API.

**How can we call it in a non-blocking way and still return to pipeline like a blocking code?** The main reason for trying a non-blocking call here is to be able to serve more HTTP Requests per server by not using a new thread per service call. The intention is not to perform some other task while IO is complete, as sequence needs to be maintained. One of the way could be to get Future, loop and check if it is done and sleep in between. Which sounds bad.

We are using Spring and have custom execution pipeline per request. I was thinking of using async-http-client for service call.

**Sample Sync Client**

```
@Component
public class SyncClient {
    private static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 1000;
    private static final int CONNECTION_REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 1000;
    private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 1000;
    private static final String URL = "http://localhost:8080/returnback";
    private static final String RETURN_BACK = "returnBack";

    private final HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder;

    public SyncClient() {
        httpClientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
        httpClientBuilder.useSystemProperties();
        httpClientBuilder.setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy());
    }

    public Map<String, String> send() throws Exception {
        final CloseableHttpClient closeableHttpClient = httpClientBuilder.build();
        final HttpRequestBase httpRequestBase = new HttpGet(URL);
        httpRequestBase.setConfig(getCustomConfig());

        final String returnBackValue = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        httpRequestBase.addHeader(new BasicHeader(RETURN_BACK, returnBackValue));

        CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
        final Map<String, String> output = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            response = closeableHttpClient.execute(httpRequestBase);
            if(response == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected null http response");
            }
            output.put(returnBackValue, response.getFirstHeader(RETURN_BACK).getValue());
        }
        finally {
            HttpClientUtils.closeQuietly(response);
        }

        return output;
    }

    private RequestConfig getCustomConfig() {
        return RequestConfig.copy(RequestConfig.DEFAULT)
                .setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT)
                .setSocketTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT)
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(CONNECTION_REQUEST_TIMEOUT).build();
    }
}
```

**Sample Polling Async Client**

```
@Component
public class PollingAsyncClient {
    private static final String URL = "http://localhost:8080/returnback";
    private static final String RETURN_BACK = "returnBack";
    private static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 1000;
    private static final int REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 1000;

    private final AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient;

    public PollingAsyncClient() {
        final AsyncHttpClientConfig asyncHttpClientConfig = new DefaultAsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder()
                .setMaxConnections(200)
                .setMaxConnectionsPerHost(20)
                .setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT).build();

        this.asyncHttpClient = new DefaultAsyncHttpClient(asyncHttpClientConfig);
    }

    public Map<String, String> send() {
        final RequestBuilder requestBuilder = new RequestBuilder("GET");
        final Request request = requestBuilder.setUrl(URL)
                .setRequestTimeout(REQUEST_TIMEOUT)
                .build();

        final String returnBackValue = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        requestBuilder.addHeader(RETURN_BACK,returnBackValue);

        ListenableFuture<Response> listenableFuture = null;
        final Map<String, String> output = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            listenableFuture = asyncHttpClient.executeRequest(request);

            while (!listenableFuture.isDone()) {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            }

            Response response = listenableFuture.get();
            output.put(returnBackValue, response.getHeader(RETURN_BACK));

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

Now the consumer can call both the clients as:

```
Map<String, String> map = null;

try {
    map = client.send();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And thus to the consumer, both of them are blocking. But per my understanding non-blocking client will consume less resources (threads). But this `sleep` loop will eat up CPU. Another way could be to use `wait` and `notify`. But that would result in creating lot of `new` objects per request. *I will try that and update, though.*

**EDIT (for comments):**
I said "sleep loop" will eat up CPU i.e. while loop will eat up, that's what I meant. As the thread will wake up and try again.

**EDIT:**

**Sample Waiting Async Client**

```
public class WaitingAsyncClient {
    private static final String URL = "http://localhost:8080/returnback";
    private static final String RETURN_BACK = "returnBack";
    private static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 2000;
    private static final int REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 2000;

    private final AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient;

    public WaitingAsyncClient() {
        final AsyncHttpClientConfig asyncHttpClientConfig = new DefaultAsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder()
                .setMaxConnections(200)
                .setMaxConnectionsPerHost(20)
                .setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT).build();

        this.asyncHttpClient = new DefaultAsyncHttpClient(asyncHttpClientConfig);
    }

    public Map<String, String> send() {
        final Object lock = new Object();
        final RequestBuilder requestBuilder = new RequestBuilder("GET");
        final Request request = requestBuilder.setUrl(URL)
                .setRequestTimeout(REQUEST_TIMEOUT)
                .build();

        final String returnBackValue = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        requestBuilder.addHeader(RETURN_BACK,returnBackValue);

        ListenableFuture<Response> listenableFuture = null;
        final Map<String, String> output = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            listenableFuture = asyncHttpClient.executeRequest(request, new AsyncHandler<Response>() {

                private final Response.ResponseBuilder builder = new Response.ResponseBuilder();

                @Override
                public void onThrowable(Throwable t) {
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        lock.notify();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public State onBodyPartReceived(HttpResponseBodyPart bodyPart) throws Exception {
                    builder.accumulate(bodyPart);
                    return State.CONTINUE;
                }

                @Override
                public State onStatusReceived(HttpResponseStatus responseStatus) throws Exception {
                    builder.accumulate(responseStatus);
                    return State.CONTINUE;
                }

                @Override
                public State onHeadersReceived(HttpResponseHeaders headers) throws Exception {
                    builder.accumulate(headers);
                    return State.CONTINUE;
                }

                @Override
                public Response onCompleted() throws Exception {
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        lock.notify();
                    }
                    return builder.build();
                }
            });

            synchronized (lock) {
                lock.wait();
            }

            Response response = listenableFuture.get();
            output.put(returnBackValue, response.getHeader(RETURN_BACK));

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

Now, I think I need to do a performance check.

Comment: If I understand this correctly you are trying to avoid an sleep in a blocking api to wait for a non blocking call. I don't see a way out of this. But I may be wrong. Using DeferredResult from the start should help you.

Comment: `sleep` doesn't eat up CPU time - instead it will cause your thread *not* to use the CPU for the specified amount of time.

Comment: The definition of sleep is to yield control, i.e yield the cpu. The quid is that a blocking thread needs to interact with a non blocking thread. You mention using less threads to serve requests. I would try deferredResult or other return type in the controller like a callable.

Comment: sleep and yield do basically the same thing as block; the thread is suspended until it becomes ready again (yield is a bit different is that the thread is ready right away, it is merely placed in the ready queue to allow other threads/processes to run).  Sorry I don't know Spring and I don't have any insight into how to get this to work.

Comment: @markspace yes, but I believe notify is better than the while.